# secure communication between c# client and java server

Tags: c#, java, ssl, certificate

I want to secure communication between simple C# WPF client and Java server. Now i have already implemented raw sockets communication, and my security is based on:

server send RSA public key to client ->

<- client send back encrypted with RSA public key, AES key for future communication.

but i'm not assured that someone (the men in the middle) will catch and replace my public key. I suppose that for avoiding men in the middle i need to use CA certificates. Can someone help me, how to make a SSL connection between Java server ans C# client using certificates ? And where i can find some certificates for testing purpose.

Comment: Stop reinventing the wheel and use SSL.

Comment: how to make a SSL connection between a java program and c#? Can you give me some real example (even using bouncycastle). If I use stadart SSL Streams i get in c# strange error as: "RemoteCertificateChainErrors"... and i don't know how to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

Start trying to see if it helps: [C# SSL](http://www.example-code.com/csharp/socket.asp) and [Java SSL](http://stilius.net/java/java_ssl.php). I can try to help more then this, if you need.

Edit:swapping links.